Auto adjusting counting in two different columns
Scenario: There are two columns(Circuit No.), the count is from left to right then a cell below the left then right and so on.
Problem: A column named as POLES can adjust the numbering, if I put 3 POLES, the target cell and the other two below will have the same count adjusting all the counting. The Poles can be [SPACE(OR NO COUNT), 1, 2 or 3]
For visual
DEFAULT: INPUT NO. OF POLES AS 18



NO. OF POLES
circuit no.
POLE
POLE
CIRCUIT NO.




18
1
1
1
2



3
1
1
4



5
1
1
6



7
1
1
8



9
1
1
10



11
1
1
12



13
1
1
14



15
1
1
16



17
1
1
18



THEN I CHANGED THE POLES AS CIRCUIT 1 AS 3 POLE THEN THE OUTPUT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS:



NO. OF POLES
circuit no.
POLE
POLE
CIRCUIT NO.




18
1
3
1
2



1
3
1
4



1
3
1
6



3
1
1
8



5
1
1
10



7
1
1
12



9
1
1
14



11
1
1
15



13
1
1
16



AND IF I CHANGE TO POLE AS SPACE AT CIRCUIT 2, 4, 6 IT WILL BE LIKE THIS



NO. OF POLES
circuit no.
POLE
POLE
CIRCUIT NO.




18
1
3
SPACE




1
3
SPACE




1
3
SPACE




3
1
1
2



5
1
1
4



7
1
1
6



9
1
1
8



11
1
1
10



13
1
1
12



THEN IF I CHANGE CIRCUIT 2 AS 2 POLES IT WILL BE LIKE THIS



NO. OF POLES
circuit no.
POLE
POLE
CIRCUIT NO.




18
1
3
SPACE




1
3
SPACE




1
3
SPACE




3
1
1
2



5
1
1
4



7
1
2
6



9
1
2
6



11
1
1
8



12
1
1
10



actually it is better if the cells will be merged if changed in 2 pole or 3 pole

Please edit your quetion to include an example of s data input, and your expected output from that data.

Also explain the logic behind assigning 3 to the second POLE column in the last three rows of your posted table.

@RonRosenfeld i edited to include the sample if data input and what will be the expected output
